# c# subForm skin as mainForm skin

Tags: c#

I have mainForm that have Skins which can be changed online and subForm that loads in MainForm. When I change the skin in MainForm, it does not change in subForm.

[form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acY7g.png)

```
namespace ERP
{
    public partial class fSchedulerGraph : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
    {
        fScheduller _fScheduller;

        public fSchedulerGraph()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fSchedulerGraph_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _fScheduller= new SpecialForms.fScheduller();
            _fScheduller.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            _fScheduller.TopLevel = false;
            _fScheduller.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            _fScheduller.Show();
            _fScheduller.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            layoutControlGroupSchedule.Controls.Add(_fScheduller);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the subForm from other Solution:

```
namespace SpecialForms
{
    public partial class fScheduller : Form
    {
        public fScheduller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's start with the fact that your sub-form is not a DevExpress ExtraForm, but a plain WinForms Form. The standard Winforms Form doesn't support theming.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed it)
Can you tell me how to convert the form?)

Comment: thank
the question quickly resolved)))
    public partial class fScheduller : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm

Comment: You can change the inheritance from `Form` to `XtraForm`. It's been a while since I've worked with DevExpress, so things may have changed since.

Comment: many thanks. it helps.